# Has this construction appeared before in the mathematical literature?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

Let $S$ be a set, which may be infinite. I define the set $HF(S)$ to be the smallest set that satisfies the following properties:

1. The empty set is in $HF(S)$.
2. Every member of $S$ is in $HF(S)$
3. Let $n$ be a positive integer. If $s_1,...,s_n$ are $n$ elements of $HF(S)$, then the set $\{s_1,...,s_n\}$ is in $HF(S)$.

I use the letters $HF$ as a reference to Hereditarily Finite. Basically, and informally, $HF(S)$ is the set of all sets that can be formed from members of $S$ using a finite number of set braces. For example, let $S$ be the set $\{\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R}\}$. Then, some members of $HF(S)$ would be $\emptyset$, $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, $\mathbb{N}$, and $\{\{\mathbb{R}\},\mathbb{N}\}$. So, has this construction appeared before in the mathematical literature, perhaps under a different name? Also, bonus question, can someone prove from the ZFC axioms that for every set $S$, there exists a unique set $HF(S)$ which satisfies my properties?

Comment: @lulu I thought the same thing - it contains every finite subset of $S$, but also others. For example $HF(\{x\}) \supset \{\emptyset, x, \{x\}, \{\{x\}\}, \ldots \}$

Comment: Re the uniqueness question, are you defining $HF(S)$ as the intersection of all sets satisfying properties 1-3? If you are, then uniqueness is immediate. And if you aren't including the "the smallest set..." part in the definition, then the solution isn't unique since we can throw in extra elements without violating the requirements.

Comment: It's just relative constructibility, a concept well-known from the 1950s.

Comment: @Karl Ok, but then how to prove existence?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think so. For example, for an infinite set $S$, $S$ itself is not in $HF(S)$. Also, unions of members of $HF(S)$ are not, in general, in $HF(S)$.

Comment: I use the letters $HF$ because, for every set $S$, $HF(S)$ will include, at the very least, every hereditarily finite set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the smallest superset of $S$ that is closed under finite subsets – that is, the least $X\supseteq S$ such that $\mathcal{P}^{<\omega}(X) \subseteq X$. To generate it from below, let:
$$
\begin{align}
&X_0 = S, \\
&X_{n+1} = X_n \cup \mathcal{P}^{\lt\omega}(X_n),
\end{align}
$$
and let
$$
X = \bigcup_{n\lt\omega} X_n.
$$
It's straightforward to check that $X$ is the desired set.